# How do I delete column from sqlite table in android?

Tags: android, sqlite

I tried deleting a column by using the following

```
openDB.execSQL("ALTER TABLE favs" + " DROP COLUMN favsCount");
```

LogCat gives the following message:

> 11-07 21:18:29.238: ERROR/Database(13952): Failure 1 (near "DROP": syntax error) on 0x34e550 when preparing 'ALTER TABLE favs DROP COLUMN favsCount'.

Is it not possible to delete fields in sqlite for Android?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Sorry, SQLite [doesn't support DROP COLUMN](http://www.sqlite.org/faq.html#q11):

> **(11) How do I add or delete columns from an existing table in SQLite.**
>
> SQLite has limited ALTER TABLE support that you can use to add a column to the end of a table or to change the name of a table. [...]
>
> For example, suppose you have a table named "t1" with columns names "a", "b", and "c" and that you want to delete column "c" from this table. The following steps illustrate how this could be done:
>
> ```
> BEGIN TRANSACTION;
> CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE t1_backup(a,b);
> INSERT INTO t1_backup SELECT a,b FROM t1;
> DROP TABLE t1;
> CREATE TABLE t1(a,b);
> INSERT INTO t1 SELECT a,b FROM t1_backup;
> DROP TABLE t1_backup;
> COMMIT;
> ```

So basically, you have to use the "copy, drop table, create new table, copy back" technique to remove a column.

Comment: Beware of the "BEGIN TRANSACTION;" and "COMMIT;" because they can block the database, as a transaction has already been commenced in `SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase()`.

Comment: @Suragch Check the documentation for `SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase()` (assuming that's what you're using of course). That bit of example SQL is quoted from the SQLite documentation BTW.

Comment: OK. I didn't know if you had any personal knowledge or experience with it. Sometimes new users leave random warnings when they don't know what they are talking about.

Comment: If you're writing a Room migration with, note that `database.execSQL` works only with single statements at a time, i.e. this would become `database.execSQL(CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE...)` `database.execSQL(INSERT INTO ...)` etc

Comment: where from will it get type of each column when creating t1_backup?

Comment: @UsmanRana: (1) The example from the SQLite documentation is meant to demonstrate the technique. (2) SQLite has a [value-based type system](https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html), not a column-based one. The column types aren't really needed by SQLite, they're needed if you have an ORM that wants to know what the table's schema is supposed to be though; the constraints, indexes, ... are needed though, see (1).

Comment: I had to specify the type of value with each column name, otherwise it was giving error that "expected type=TEXT, founf type=null"

Comment: @UsmanRana Perhaps you should report a bug to the SQLite documentation maintainers, that's straight out of the official documentation.

Answer (score 5):

as mu is too short says Sqlite doesn't allow to do an alter table to delete a column. here you can see the [alter syntax definition](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_altertable.html)