# Cannot delete column from sqlite table [Android]

Tags: android, sqlite

Since I cannot comment here : [How do I delete column from sqlite table in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8045249/how-do-i-delete-column-from-sqlite-table-in-android)

I do the method and not work at all, the column is still exist. Here's my SQL :

```
db.execSQL("CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE Evaluation_backup(" + allColumnName + ");" 
                    + "INSERT INTO Evaluation_backup SELECT " + allColumnName + " FROM Evaluation;"
                    + "DROP TABLE Evaluation;" 
                    + "CREATE TABLE Evaluation("+ allColumnName + ");" 
                    + "INSERT INTO Evaluation SELECT " + allColumnName + " FROM Evaluation_backup;"
                    + "DROP TABLE Evaluation_backup;");
```

The `allColumnName` is `String` contains all the column names except the name of the column that I want to remove. The `allColumnName` content like this: `column1,column2,column3`.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: is your table created with these commands?

Comment: I have checked the string 'allColumnName'. My table still exist with the all column (I didn't knew the table was created or this SQL not worked). By the way, I have successfully added new column in the table.

Comment: What do you mean @d'alar'cop? Sorry I don't get it.

Comment: I speak rubbish - never mind.

Comment: This is a typo I suppose? "Evaluasi_backup(" - should be Evaluation_backup

Comment: try to delete the last line then check the content of Evaluation backup

Comment: You have questoid don't you?

Comment: Yes, I've tried. There is no Evaluation_backup. Thanks, I think there is something wrong in this SQL. Because, I've tried any SQL and worked at all.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [documentation for `execSql`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#execSQL%28java.lang.String%29) says:

> Execute a single SQL statement …

Call `db.execSql` once for each statement.

Comment: Yeah it's worked, thanks master @CL. :D and I feel sorry for the documentation :(